# Unrecognised Selector when using nicklockwood's CountryPicker in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know they say there is no such thing as a stupid question, but I feel stupid since I know this question has been asked dozens of times before, but I can't seem to find one of the solutions which fit my case (I have made the effort of looking).

So the problem I face is that I am creating a Swift iOS project, and am looking to implement a country picker. From what i can tell, there is no native solution for that array of countries, so I came across what looks to be a nice custom solution by 'NickLockWood' ( https://github.com/nicklockwood/CountryPicker )

And the problem is that I am having a little trouble trying to get it to work in my Swift project, since all the sample and demo code provided is in obj-c (I am in the process of getting better at converting such code from one language to another, but I appear to not be at the ninja level yet for this..).

From what I can tell, this is how he uses it in his viewController

```
- (void)countryPicker:(__unused CountryPicker *)picker didSelectCountryWithName:(NSString *)name code:(NSString *)code
{
self.nameLabel.text = name;
self.codeLabel.text = code;
}
```

I have managed to try convert that into my Swift viewController as such..

```
func countryPicker(picker: CountryPicker?, didSelectCountryWithName name: String!, code: String!) {
    println("\(name)")
    println("\(code)")
}
```

So when the app launches, the listPicker is populated with country names and the associated flags. So I have a good feeling it is hooked up mostly correctly.
The error occurs when I spin the picker and it lands on a selection. I then get this...

```
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController countryPicker:didSelectCountryWithName:code:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17dca740'
```

In my ViewController, where this picker is associated with, I used the storyboard to link the 'CountryPicker' delegate to the ViewController.
Then in the ViewController this is my code..

```
import UIKit

class RegionViewController: UIViewController, CountryPickerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func countryPicker(picker: CountryPicker!, didSelectCountryWithName name: String!, code: String!) {
    println("\(name)")
    println("\(code)")
}
```

Am I perhaps missing something else here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try making the class & func public. Does that help?

Comment: You didn't show all your code, but did you set the delegate property for the countryPicker? ie, `self.countryPicker.delegate = self`?

Comment: @tng, besides for the CountryPicker.h and CountryPicker.m files, that is all my code associated with the picker. I associated the delegate via the storyboard by selecting the picker controller, viewing the Connections Inespector, and asscoiating the delegate to the ViewController it is in.
Do I need to do more than that as well in the ViewController file itself?

Comment: @SimonZA I would try `self.countryPicker.delegate = self` in your `viewDidLoad`. Typically you need to set the delegate instance.

Comment: Oh my sack. Turns out it was my error. I didnt associate the ViewController in the storyboard to use the custom RegionViewController class. As soon as I did that, all worked well with no need for other code.
Thanks all for the assistance though! Much appreciated!

Comment: Without even looking at the spec I can tell you that UIViewController does not implement `countryPicker:didSelectCountryWithName:code:`.  You need to call the method with a pointer to *your* view controller, not a UIViewController.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @HotLicks. Turns out it was indeed my error.

Pity that people downvote questions without giving the poster a reason why. I would delete the question, but maybe I would think it would help someone else down the road who might, mistakingly, do a similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error.

I hadnt associated the viewController I was working on in the storyboard to use the custom RegionViewController I was trying to reach.

Fixed that connection and all was right again.

Thanks!